# How to save state when extending UIComponentBase

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, composite-component, state-saving

I'm creating a composite component that will wrap a datatable to implement very simple paging. I need to save state (the current page number) between ajax requests.

I tried creating fields in my FacesComponent, but I discovered they are wiped out during the JSF lifecycle:

```
@FacesComponent(value = "bfTableComponent")
public class BFTableComponent extends UIComponentBase implements NamingContainer {

    private int currentPageNumber;
    ...
```

I can't seems to find a concise guide to doing this anywhere! How would one save state between requests when creating a composite component?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`StateHelper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/StateHelper.html). It's available by [`UIComponent#getStateHelper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper%28%29).

```
private enum PropertyKeys {
    currentPageNumber;
}

public void setCurrentPageNumber(int currentPageNumber) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.currentPageNumber, currentPageNumber);
}

public int getCurrentPageNumber() {
    return (int) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.currentPageNumber, 0);
}
```

Note that I'm returning a default value of `0` in the getter. You might want to change `int` to `Integer` and remove the default value so that `null` will be returned.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you can for more simplicity also just extend [`UINamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) instead of implementing `NamingContainer`. This way you can omit the overridden `getFamily()` method as it's already implemented rightly by `UINamingContainer`.

Comment: A quick followup, if I wanted to run some "One Time" initialization code, and save it to the StateHelper, what would be the appropriate place to do that? I tried the constructor BFTableComponent but that did not have the properties available yet, and it's run multiple times.

Comment: Is it static data? Make it a `static` variable. If initialization is complex, you could do it in a `static {}`.

Comment: Nope, not static. one of the attributes is that a user can select the initial page. I want to set that exactly once. Is there a place for one time initialization?

Comment: Sounds more like candidate for a backing bean property, not an UIComponent attribute. Use a managed bean instead for that attribute.

Comment: Ok. But for future reference, no such construct is available? There is no way to run initialization code for a FacesComponent?

Comment: You can use the constructor for that, but you're apparently relying on an external model value, for that you should be using a managed bean instead.

Comment: did you find an appropriate solution, exabrial? I have a similar requirement (encapsulated state in the component with an inital value provided by client). But I am in doubt, that such requirement fits into the concept at all.