# JSF Composite Component for MultilingualString object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm writing a JSF application which needs to be internationalized. To do so, I created a MultilingualString :

```
public class MultilingualString {
    /* The Language class is basically a wrapper for a java.util.Locale */
    private Map<Language, String> strings;

    /* business methods, getters, setters */
}
```

Now, there are multiple forms which needs to fill a MultilingualString, and it's quite ugly to repeat a c:forEach loop each time I need to put such an object in a form. So I heard about JSF Composite Components, and I tried to write one for that purpose.

Here is my inputMultilingualString.xhtml :

```
<ui:component xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
              xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
              xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
              xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <composite:interface componentType="inputMultilingualString">
        <composite:attribute name="value" required="true"
                             type="com.tob.entities.internationalization.MultilingualString"/>
        <composite:attribute name="languages" type="java.util.List" default="#{null}"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cc.init}"/>
        <h:dataTable id="#{cc.clientId}" value="#{cc.languages}" var="language">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{language}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:inputText binding="#{cc.inputs[language]}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

So I want to the value attribute to be an instance of MultilingualString and the languages attribute to be an instance of List of Language.
If the languages attribute is null, I want te composite component to display a row in the dataTable for each entry in the map contained in the MultilingualString.

Now here is my "backing component" in InputMultilingualString.java :

```
@FacesComponent(value = "inputMultilingualString", createTag = true)
public class InputMultilingualString extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    private final Map<Language, UIInput> inputs = new HashMap();
    private List<Language> languages;

    @Override
    public String getFamily() {
        return (UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY);
    }

    public void init() {
        List<Language> ls = (List<Language>) this.getAttributes().get("languages");
        MultilingualString ms = (MultilingualString) this.getValue();

        /* Setting languages */
        if (ls != null) {
            this.setLanguages(ls);
        } else {
            this.languages = new ArrayList();
            this.languages.addAll(ms.getStrings().keySet());
        }

        /* Initializing inputs */
        UIInput tmp;
        for (Language l : this.languages) {
            tmp = new UIInput();
            tmp.setValue(ms.getString(l));//
            this.inputs.put(l, tmp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getSubmittedValue() {
        String ret = new String();

        for (Map.Entry<Language, UIInput> entry : this.inputs.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() != null) {
                if (!ret.isEmpty()) {
                    ret += ',';
                }
                ret += entry.getKey().getLanguageTag(); // NullPointerException here when the form is submitted
                ret += "=" + entry.getValue().getSubmittedValue();
            }
        }
        return (ret);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, Object submittedValue) {
        MultilingualString ms = (MultilingualString) this.getValue();
        String[] entries = ((String) submittedValue).split(",");
        String[] pair;
        Language language;

        for (String entry : entries) {
            pair = entry.split("=");
            language = new Language();
            language.setLanguageTag(pair[0]);
            ms.addString(language, pair[1]);
        }
        return (ms);
    }

    public List<Language> getLanguages() {
        return (this.languages);
    }

    public void setLanguages(List<Language> languages) {
        this.languages = languages;
    }

    public Map<Language, UIInput> getInputs() {
        return (this.inputs);
    }
}
```

In order to implement the rule on which languages I want to display an input, I added a languages attribute to the backing component and initialized it in the init method which is called on the preRenderComponent event.
The languages list is correctly initialized.

Here is how I use my composite component :

```
<ui:composition template="/Templates/Common.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:tob="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="testForm">
            <tob:inputMultilingualString value="#{testBean.ms}" languages="#{testBean.languages}"/>
            <!-- The testBean.ms contains :
                     [English]  => string-English
                     [français] => string-français
                     [русский]  => string-русский

                 And the testBean.languages contains a list of Language objects for English, French, and Russian -->
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{testBean.submit()}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The problems are :

- If the MultilingualString entered as value already contains some strings, they are not displayed in the inputText as it would be if you fill the inputText value attribute (I read the [article of BalusC on the topic](http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html) and he doesn't need to fill the value attribute to make his drop down lists have the correct value). I read on a BalusC's answer somewhere on stackoverflow that the UIInput referenced in the binding attribute of the inputText is created if it's evaluated to null, that's why I tried to initialized them in the init method, but so far no luck.
- When I submit the form, I get an NullPointerException at the getKey() call in the getSubmittedValue() method. How is that possible ?

I hope that was clear and that someone can help me !
Thanks !

Edit :
I'm using GlassFish 4 and I manually updated Mojarra to 2.2.6

Comment: The whole page shouldn't display at all but already fail during page load with an EL exception on `binding`. You namely can't use `binding` on a render time variable which is `null` during view build time. Did you really use `<h:dataTable>` in your code? Isn't that actually a `<c:forEach>`? I can point out the actual mistake as to the described failure during postback, but the given code already fails during display so I'm confused now.

Comment: @BalusC I copy-pasted the code I wrote in the question, and the page does display. So I understand it's not possible to use a `<h:dataTable>` here. But won't the problem be the same with `<c:forEach>` ? I will still not be able to initialize my `Map<Language, UIInput>`.

Comment: What JSF impl/version? It fails on Mojarra 2.2.6. But anyway, the requirement is understood. This all is just possible without the need for a backing component, I'll bake an answer.

Comment: @BalusC Just this one : Mojarra 2.2.6. GlassFish starting output sample : `Initialisation de Mojarra 2.2.6 ( 20140304-1537 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.6@12949)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 technical problems in the code posted so far:

1. You're using `binding` on a variable which is only available during view render time. The `binding` attribute runs during view build time, not during view render time. In this particular case, when the `binding` is executed, the `#{language}` is `null`. See also [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-binding-attribute-in-jsf-works). Also you seem to expect that multiple `<h:inputText>` components would be generated, but that's not true. There's only one which is reused multiple times during rendering the view. Only when you have used `<c:forEach>` instead of `<h:dataTable>`, then indeed physically multiple `<h:inputText>` components would be generated. See also [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
2. You're not saving the state of the component for the postback. You should be removing the `languages` property and let the getter and setter delegate to `getStateHelper()`. See also [How to save state when extending UIComponentBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405278/how-to-save-state-when-extending-uicomponentbase).

However, the overall approach is clumsy. You don't need a backing component for the functional requirement. Just add a `List<Languages>` getter to the `MultilingualString` and use it directly as `default` of `languages` attribute.

So, if you add this to `MultilingualString`:

```
public List<Language> getLanguages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(strings.keySet());
}
```

And then just reference the attribtues via `#{cc.attrs}`:

```html
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true" type="com.tob.entities.internationalization.MultilingualString"/>
    <cc:attribute name="languages" type="java.util.List" default="#{cc.attrs.value.languages}" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.languages}" var="language">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{language}"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value.strings[language]}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</cc:implementation>
```

Then it should work as intented. Note the possibility to use the brace notation `[]` to reference a dynamic map key. That's perhaps the whole key to your solution (you seems to be not aware of that and hence working towards an overcomplicated solution).

Comment: Indeed, seeing your answer, the initial approach was clearly overcomplicated. Thanks for the answer and the `MultilingualString.getLanguages()` trick !