# Understanding JSF components class lifetime

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

What's the component's lifetime? Traversing the `UIInput` sources I've noticed that there's local field called `value` which is essentailly the value of the component. I've also noticed that after processing all convertion and validation we compare a new value with an old value of the component and if they're different fire valueChange event. Actually, here's the piece of code taking over the quing events:

```
if (isValid()) {
     Object previous = getValue();
     setValue(newValue);
     setSubmittedValue(null);
     if (compareValues(previous, newValue)) {
         queueEvent(new ValueChangeEvent(this, previous, newValue)); // <-----
     }
}
```

But if the component were killed after any request, we would simply get `ValueChangeEvent` eny time we send a request. So, I presume the component's lifetime is the same as the bean's lifetime which the component bound to the property to. But I couldn't find any documental assurance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component instances are request scoped. Only component properties which are delegated to [`UIComponent#getStateHelper()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper--) are view scoped. I.e. they are saved in the JSF view state. This covers among others the [`ValueHolder#getLocalValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html#getLocalValue--) which the `getValue()` is delegating to.

```
@Override
public Object getValue() {
    return isLocalValueSet() ? getLocalValue() : super.getValue();
}
```

Only on stateless views, i.e. pages with `<f:view transient="true">`, the behavior as you described *"we would simply get ValueChangeEvent eny time we send a request"* will indeed happen.

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [How to save state when extending UIComponentBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405278/how-to-save-state-when-extending-uicomponentbase/)
- [What is the usefulness of statelessness in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890995/what-is-the-usefulness-of-statelessness-in-jsf)

Comment: Is it true that the ViewState decoding and setting the `defaultMap` property of the `ComponentStateHelper` (`StateHelper` for the `UIInput`) are performed during the ViewBuild time? So, if the value of a component is in ViewState, then we have the `isLocalValueSet()` returns `true` and the method getValue() just returns the value from the map?

Comment: No, it's performed during restore view phase. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/31890433 to learn the difference. As to the `isLocalValueSet()`, this is just another property (also view scoped!) indicating that the local value is set, because it's valid to have a null local value and thus a nullcheck wouldn't work, the component would otherwise erroneously return model value via `getValue()`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I presume that's not directly related to the question, but how does JSF engine do things on the ViewState? Since you said __[...]are view scoped. I.e. they are saved in the JSF view state__, I'd guess that we have an empty view state to be created __iff__  `ViewId`'s changed. Is that correct?

Comment: The key is the value of the `javax.faces.ViewState` request parameter.