# How to detect valueChange event in validator?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

Mojarra 2.1

I need to write a validator for the `h:inputText` which performs some logic only if the value for that input is changed. I.e.

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator{

    public void validate(FacesContext context,
                         UIComponent component,
                         Object value) throws ValidatorException;
         if(valueChanged(UIComponent component)){ //The method checks if the value's changed
               //do some piece of logic
         }
         return;
     }
}
```

I dug into the queuing events of the `UIInput` and found this:

```
validateValue(context, newValue);

// If our value is valid, store the new value, erase the
// "submitted" value, and emit a ValueChangeEvent if appropriate
if (isValid()) {
        Object previous = getValue();
        setValue(newValue);
        setSubmittedValue(null);
        if (compareValues(previous, newValue)) {
            queueEvent(new ValueChangeEvent(this, previous, newValue));
        }
    }
```

This piece of code is from the method, executed by the Validation phase callback. The first thought that popped into my head was queriyng all events fired during handling the request. The method `queueEvent(FacesEvent)` is implemented as follows:

```
 public void queueEvent(FacesEvent event) {

    if (event == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    UIComponent parent = getParent();
    if (parent == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    } else {
        parent.queueEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Therefore every such invokation will end up in `UIViewRoot.queueEvent(FacesEvent)` which is implemented as:

```
public void queueEvent(FacesEvent event) {

    if (event == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    // We are a UIViewRoot, so no need to check for the ISE
    if (events == null) {
        int len = PhaseId.VALUES.size();
        List<List<FacesEvent>> events = new ArrayList<List<FacesEvent>>(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            events.add(new ArrayList<FacesEvent>(5));
        }
        this.events = events;
    }
    events.get(event.getPhaseId().getOrdinal()).add(event);
}
```

Which means, all events is actually stored as a `List<List<FacesEvent>>` for each phase. But the `List<List<FacesEvent>> events` is a private field, so it's impossible to get direct acces to it.

Another thing is that the actual validation is being perfromed before the `quingEvent`, so implemting `valueChangeListener` doesn't seem useful as well.

***Question***: Is it possible to implements such validator in `JSF` in a *natural way*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the value comparison yourself. In the validator, the old value is just readily available via `UIComponent` argument.

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue) {
    if (component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
        Object newValue = submittedValue;
        Object oldValue = ((EditableValueHolder) component).getValue();

        if (newValue == null ? oldValue == null : newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            return; // Not changed, so skip validation.
        }
    }

    // Do actual validation here.
}
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), it has a [`ValueChangeValidator`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/ValueChangeValidator) which does exactly this.

Comment: One more clarification: The `getValue()` method takes the value directly from the decoded `ViewState`?

Comment: This part is essentially answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955955/understanding-jsf-components-class-lifetime/31958332#31958332 So, only if the local value is set (i.e. the previously submitted value didn't made it to update model values phase), it's basically grabbed from the view state.